# Omitting "to be" from a sentence before adjective

Tags: adjectives

I have noticed many a time that some sentences do not use "to be" before an adjective.

For example:

> the things that I learned from that book have proven (to be) useful to me time and again.

Does omitting "to be" from the above sentence change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no difference, and the 'to be' is entirely optional.

However, I think in some cases there *is* a slight difference, in that the 'to be' makes it more clear that you're talking about a short term state rather than an inherent trait of the subject.

For example:

- "He seems cold" could mean he seems to be chilled *or* that he seems emotionally distant.
- "He seems to be cold" unambiguously means chilled.